# How do I style (css) radio buttons and labels?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, styles

Given the code bellow, how do I style the radio buttons to be next to the labels and style the label of the selected radio button differently than the other labels?

```html
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.2/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.2/build/base/base-min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="input radio">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>What color is the sky?</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="color" value="" id="SubmitQuestion" />
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="SubmitQuestion1" value="1"  />
    <label for="SubmitQuestion1">A strange radient green.</label>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="SubmitQuestion2" value="2"  />
    <label for="SubmitQuestion2">A dark gloomy orange</label>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="SubmitQuestion3" value="3"  />
    <label for="SubmitQuestion3">A perfect glittering blue</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Also let me state that I use the yui css styles as base. If you are not familir with them, they can be found here:

- [reset-fonts-grids.css](http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.2/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css)
- [base-min.css](http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.2/build/base/base-min.css)

Documentation for them both here : [Yahoo! UI Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

@pkaeding: Thanks. I tried some floating both thing that just looked messed up. The styling active radio button seemed to be doable with some input[type=radio]:active nomination on a google search, but I didnt get it to work properly. So the question I guess is more: Is this possible on all of todays modern browsers, and if not, what is the minimal JS needed?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first part of your question can be solved with just HTML & CSS; you'll need to use Javascript for the second part.

#### Getting the Label Near the Radio Button

I'm not sure what you mean by "next to": on the same line and near, or on separate lines? If you want all of the radio buttons on the same line, just use margins to push them apart. If you want each of them on their own line, you have two options (unless you want to venture into `float:` territory):

- Use `<br />s`  to split the options apart and some CSS to vertically align them:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .input input
    {
        width: 20px;
    }
</style>
<div class="input radio">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>What color is the sky?</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Submit][question]" value="" id="SubmitQuestion" />

        <input type="radio" name="data[Submit][question]" id="SubmitQuestion1" value="1"  />
        <label for="SubmitQuestion1">A strange radient green.</label>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="data[Submit][question]" id="SubmitQuestion2" value="2"  />
        <label for="SubmitQuestion2">A dark gloomy orange</label>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="data[Submit][question]" id="SubmitQuestion3" value="3"  />
        <label for="SubmitQuestion3">A perfect glittering blue</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

- Follow *A List Apart*'s article: [Prettier Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms)

#### Applying a Style to the Currently Selected Label + Radio Button

Styling the `<label>` is why you'll need to resort to Javascript. A library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com)
is perfect for this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .input label.focused
    {
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.input :radio').focus(updateSelectedStyle);
        $('.input :radio').blur(updateSelectedStyle);
        $('.input :radio').change(updateSelectedStyle);
    })

    function updateSelectedStyle() {
        $('.input :radio').removeClass('focused').next().removeClass('focused');
        $('.input :radio:checked').addClass('focused').next().addClass('focused');
    }
</script>
```

The `focus` and `blur` hooks are needed to make this work in IE.

Answer (score 27):

For any CSS3-enabled browser you can use an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) for styling your labels

```css
input:checked + label {
    color: white;
}
```

MDN's [browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility) says essentially all of the current, popular browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari), on both desktop and mobile, are compatible.

Comment: Nice! Works well with firefox which is enought for this internal webapp. This is the cleanest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This will get your buttons and labels next to each other, at least.  I believe the second part can't be done in css alone, and will need javascript.  I found a page that might help you with that part as well, but I don't have time right now to try it out: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/6942.htm

```
<style type="text/css">
.input input {
  float: left;
}
.input label {
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
<div class="input radio">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>What color is the sky?</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Submit][question]" value="" id="SubmitQuestion" />

        <input type="radio" name="data[Submit][question]" id="SubmitQuestion1" value="1"  />
        <label for="SubmitQuestion1">A strange radient green.</label>

        <input type="radio" name="data[Submit][question]" id="SubmitQuestion2" value="2"  />
        <label for="SubmitQuestion2">A dark gloomy orange</label>
        <input type="radio" name="data[Submit][question]" id="SubmitQuestion3" value="3"  />
        <label for="SubmitQuestion3">A perfect glittering blue</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```